# Json serialize ignore attributes like "JsonPropertyName" and use native property names

Tags: json, serialization

I have a class returned from api:

```
public class Employee {
  [JsonPropertyName("FIRST_NAME")]
  public string FirstName {get;set;}
  [JsonPropertyName("LAST_NAME")]
  public string LastName {get;set;}
  [JsonPropertyName("EMP_NUM")]
  public string EmployeeId {get;set;}
}
```

From api I receive json

```
{"FirstName":"AAA","LastName":"BBB","EmployeeId":"111"}
```

Now I need to build another json for export:

```
{"FIRST_NAME":"AAA","LAST_NAME":"BBB","EMP_NUM":"111"}
```

So how I can desirialize "Employee" ignore attributes, with native names, and serialize "Employee" using attributes

Something like:

```
await using Stream stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions() { "IgnoreAttributes, and use native names" } 
List<Employee> employees = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<Employee>>(stream, options);
```